# sum the values using For-Next Loop

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to sum the values of all values being run through the for loop. E.g, Column A has 5 values,  A1=1 , A2=2 , A3=3, A4=4 , A5=5. I am trying to sum up all the values when the loop runs . I need it to calculate my project profit and loss , the example illustrated is just a simple one of course for the sake of my understanding

This is my code that I am stuck at.

```
Sub test()
Dim a As Long

Dim i As Long

 a = 0
 For i = 1 To 5
   a = Range("A" & i).Value
   
 Next i

   
 
End Sub
```

Comment: `a = a + Range("A" & i).Value`    Use `Dim a As Double` if your values aren't all whole numbers.

Comment: @TimWilliams, aaah, that's what I was missing. Thank you , Tim! :-)

Comment: If the range gets large then the repeated accesses to the worksheet could get quite slow.  A faster approach would be to get the excel range into a VBA array, which is quite easy to do.  You can then use a For each loop to sum the values in the array.  But the question that must also be asked is why don't you use the worksheet function sum or sumif to get the sum of the values?

Comment: @freeflow  The answer to your question on not using worksheet function  is because we are dealing with an ever expanding arrays( range). The example I illustrated has fixed range , but in my actual data, I have an expanding data which I will need to analyze to calculate the proect profit/loss. Using  a for loop, I could easily loop through to from the start row to the last row using the Range("xx" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row.  sumif/sum.

Comment: @freeflow,And to complicate matters it involves a lot of IF conditions with OR/AND combinations  , which I dont think can be achieved using the sumifs/sum worksheet function

Comment: @freeflow, I belive that sumifs/sum could accomodate the ever expanding array, but I don' think there is a way to get around the complicated nested OR/AND conditions. But again, I might be wrong, perhaps an expert could find a way around it.

Comment: OK, the complicated Or/AND are likely to be an issue so no worries there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You almost got it correct. Here is solution

```
Sub test()
Dim a As Long

Dim i As Long

 a = 0
 For i = 1 To 5
   a = a + Range("A" & i).Value
   
 Next i

    
 
End Sub
```